# Spring Boot+JPA+Redis Cache+LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, redis

1) I use spring-boot 1.5.3,jpa.redis as cache provider

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "product",key = "#id")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Product getOne(long id) {
    return repository.findOne(id);
}
```

this is entity attr:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade =CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 private List<ProductAttr> productAttrs;
```

2) when I get product from redis cache,throws org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.xx.domain.product.Product.productAttrs, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.clear(PersistentBag.java:381) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
```

but i use jcache is ok.i debuged and found PersistentBag throws LazyInitializationException .
how to fix it ?

3、this is my RedisCacheConfig

```
  @Value(value = "${spring.redis.host}")
    private String hostName;

@Value(value = "${spring.redis.port}")
private String port;

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHostName(hostName);
    factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
    factory.setUsePool(true);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
    cacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
    cacheManager.setLoadRemoteCachesOnStartup(true);
    cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Comment: i got the same question, have you solved it? :)

Comment: @Yuan Li did u resolve this issue ?